# Java - PDFBox - Text Extraction

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have been using pdfbox for extracting text information from PDFs. I have succesfully parsed all properties of text such as fontname , fontface , size ,position etc.

**PROBLEM:** I am using pdfbox1.2.1(latest version). The getCharacter() in TextPosition class returns the full string except the last character. The last character is parsed as a separate string.

Ex:  "How are you" is parsed as "How are yo" and "u" (2 separate strings).

I dont want it to happen that way..

Has anybody come accross this? .. Am i doing something wrong??.. Waiting for reply..

Thanks and Regards,
Magggi

Comment: I don't think you're using it wrong. There is a PDF I work with that returns **every character** as a separate `String`. Unfortunately, I don't really have much of a solution for you. I would be curious to know the answer too.

Comment: I am able to extract lines of text from PDF.But within every line, the split as mentioned above occurs.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is solved.

The following code in `processEncodedText( byte[] string )` in `PDFStreamEngine.java`

```
if( spacingText == 0 && (i + codeLength) < (string.length - 1) )
{
    continue;
}
```

should be changed to

```
if( spacingText == 0 && (i + codeLength) < (string.length) )
{
    continue;
}
```

Regards,
Maggi

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This issue is solved by pdfbox.
Try latest version of pdfbox. The latest version can be downloaded from http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html